Where is the reference to Suta Samhita in the Srikara Bhasya of Sripati Panditaradhya?
Suta Samhita is part of SKanda Purana but many need the reference for its authenticity. So is there any reference available to Suta Samhita in any bhashya or elsewhere

Yes there is mention of Suta samhita in Srikara Bhasya of Sripati Panditaradhya
